# Create a folder in the /root directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, directory

I've tried everything online but I couldn't find a real solution, I have a php file that in local on my computer works perfectly, instead when I load it on my seerver it doesn't create the folder.
the php contains this string to create a new folder:

```
shell_exec("mkdir /root/users/$username");
```

I guess that maybe it's a problem of permission, I can just create folders in the var/www folder, dI tried a lot of different way to set my permission but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What user is this script running as? Does that user have permissions on the /root/users directory? This seems very straight-forward.

Comment: For Mac OS refer to this 
https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/01/18/creating-root-level-directories-and-symbolic-links-on-macos-catalina/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mkdir` to create folder or `chmod` to change permissions functions.

for example:

```
mkdir('newFolder', 775);
```

or you want to create on some path. Currently you are in `/home/username/public_html/project/`

```
mkdir('subproject', 775); // it will create in `project` folder.
```

if you want to create with some root like you asked in your question.

```
mkdir('/root/users/'.$username, 775);
```

I am sure it will be fix your issue and also a standard way to create.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, i've tried all 4 methods but stlll I can create folders just in /var/www there's no way to create the folder in the root directory or in any other directory.. the user that i'm using is the root.

Comment: Ok then you may define your project's root path in a variable or constant and write code like `mkdir(PATH.'foldername', 755)`

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, then I searched on the web, i'm trying to change the permission with the root user typing (chown -R www-data .) but it says (chown: changing ownership of './lib/lxcfs/cgroup': Operation not permitted)

Comment: seems issue with permissions.